# Start Windows Service From Application without Admin right(c++)

Tags: c++, windows, service

I wrote a windows service (and it runs fine). Now i have a separate app where I want to start this service from, but it seems this is not possible without administrator rights.

How would a proper solution look like that a user can start/stop the service (e.g. from a tray or application)

IMHO its bad that the application must always be started with administrator rights.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to change the permissions on the service object, preferably at the same time you install it.

```
wchar_t sddl[] = L"D:"
  L"(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)"           // default permissions for local system
  L"(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)"   // default permissions for administrators
  L"(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)"                 // default permissions for authenticated users
  L"(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)"           // default permissions for power users
  L"(A;;RP;;;IU)"                           // added permission: start service for interactive users
  ;

PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;

if (!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(sddl, SDDL_REVISION_1, &sd, NULL))
{
   fail();
}

if (!SetServiceObjectSecurity(service, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd))
{
   fail();
}
```

I'm assuming here you've already opened the service handle.  You need WRITE_DAC permission.

If you also want non-admin users to be able to stop the service, add the WP right, i.e.,

```
L"(A;;RPWP;;;IU)"                           
  // added permissions: start service, stop service for interactive users
```

SDDL codes for service rights can be found in Wayne Martin's blog entry, [Service Control Manager Security for non-admins](http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.co.nz/2009/10/service-control-manager-security-for.html).

Answer (score 1):

@Harry Johnston, in addition to response.

Here is c++ builder example.

```
void __fastcall TService1::ServiceAfterInstall(TService *Sender)
{
 wchar_t lpBuffer[256];
 long errorCode;
 SC_HANDLE hSCManager,hService;

 hSCManager  = OpenSCManager(0, 0, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
 if (hSCManager == NULL)
 {
   errorCode = GetLastError();
   FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, errorCode,MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), lpBuffer, 256, NULL);
   LogMessage("OpenSCManager Error "+AnsiString(lpBuffer), EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE);
   return;
 }


 hService = OpenService(hSCManager, this->Name.c_str(), READ_CONTROL | WRITE_DAC);
 if (hService == NULL)
 {
   errorCode = GetLastError();
   FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, errorCode,MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), lpBuffer, 256, NULL);
   LogMessage("OpenService Error "+AnsiString(lpBuffer), EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE);
   CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
 }

 wchar_t sddl[] = L"D:"
  L"(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)"           // default permissions for local system
  L"(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)"   // default permissions for administrators
  L"(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)"                 // default permissions for authenticated users
  L"(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)"           // default permissions for power users
  L"(A;;RP;;;IU)"                           // added permission: start service for interactive users
  ;

  PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
  if (!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(AnsiString(sddl).c_str(), SDDL_REVISION_1, &sd, NULL))
  {
    errorCode = GetLastError();
    FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, errorCode,MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), lpBuffer, 256, NULL);
    LogMessage("ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor Error "+AnsiString(lpBuffer), EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE);
  }

  if (!SetServiceObjectSecurity(hService, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd))
  {
    errorCode = GetLastError();
    FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, errorCode,MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), lpBuffer, 256, NULL);
    LogMessage("SetServiceObjectSecurity Error "+AnsiString(lpBuffer), EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE);
  }

  CloseServiceHandle(hService);
  CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
}
```

Comment: The construction `AnsiString(sddl).c_str()` is redundant: since `sddl` is only used once you can change the definition to `char` and use narrow strings if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a service programmatically is done with the [`StartService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. There is a comprehensive usage example also given under the title [starting a service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which also shows how to:

- detect that the service is for some reason shutting down
- wait until the service is in a stable state (started/stopped)
- start the service programmatically

As for administrator rights, this is necessary because if just about any application could shut services down (or, more importantly, *install and start new services*) there would be very real and very serious security issues.

Answer (score 0):

@Harry Johnston 's worked fine for me, in case someone wants to do this in C#:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetServiceObjectSecurity(SafeHandle serviceHandle,
    UInt32 secInfos,
    IntPtr lpSecDesrBuf);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern Boolean ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String strSecurityDescriptor,
    UInt32 sDRevision,
    ref IntPtr securityDescriptor,
    ref UInt32 securityDescriptorSize);

public static void SetServicePermissions(string service)
{
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(service);
    bool ok;
    IntPtr pSD = IntPtr.Zero;
    uint securityDescriptorSize = 0;
    string secDesc = "D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)(A;;RPWP;;;IU)";

    ok = ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(secDesc, 1, ref pSD, ref securityDescriptorSize);
    if (!ok)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("error calling ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(): error code=" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    ok = SetServiceObjectSecurity(sc.ServiceHandle, 4 , pSD);
    if (!ok)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("error calling SetServiceObjectSecurity(); error code=" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
}
```

Comment: As I wrote it's the C# equivalent of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8380009/1349529