# Is it possible to store some Install Privileges without storing the password?

Tags: .net, windows

I have an application and would like it to upgrade itself. I am storing a windows user name & password and launching an elevated session to install the setup.

Although the user name & password are encrypted, some clients are not at ease with this, which I can understand.

Is there a way I can use some sort of ***token*** which elevates the session to Admin rights without storing the user name & password and where this token is valid only on that specific machine?

Regards

JP

Comment: What about creating a new user with the required privileges? Exactly what you requires, no more and no less. You will run your updates under that user. Otherwise you may install a service required to run on elevated privileges and you will perform updates with it

Comment: To continue on what Adriano said, or you set the permissions of the folder with the files that are likely needed to be update to be user writeable, then you don't need elevation to be updated.

Comment: Far better to use a service than to create a user account IMO.  Make sure the service is configured to start only on demand.  [You can configure a service to be startable without admin privilege.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8380009/886887)  However you do it, make sure that it verifies the integrity and source of the downloaded update, e.g., using digital signatures.